# Int sequence without an array

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

Hey I’m really stuck and confused I need to basically make an integer sequence without using arrays and it has to finish asking you how many numbers you want to input when you give the value of 0 to one of them? I’m really new to it and I’m struggling a lot

Comment: unclear what you are asking?

Comment: make use of loops, for example 'for loop'

Comment: Ask the n, for int i = 0; i < n; ++i ask an int print the int.

Comment: I can’t use arrays I have to do it a different way

Comment: @GaryDekuHergest who is talking about arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is even more confusing... Anyways simply use List, and then you can add as many values as you want. If you need to keep only unique values then use Set.

```
List integerSequence = new ArrayList();
integerSequence.add(1);
...
integerSequence.add(n);
```

Comment: I can’t use arrays

Comment: @GaryDekuHergest there is no array used (do not be confused with Object name `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you asked is, that you want to read integers (from stdin) till the value 0 is entered, so, you do it like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ReadInts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            // without error checking
            int val = Integer.valueOf(line);
            if (val == 0) {
                br.close();
                break;
            }
            list.add(val);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        // print at the end, just to check
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added I also need to have it print smallest largest,range, sum, amount of numbers entered and finally the average of the numbers

Comment: You should start studying instead of asking here for someone to do your homework...If you have troubles understanding any kind of matter then please point your dedicated question but do not ask us to do the whole assignment.